# Ruby: Get from string "parts of the same string" - this between that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, rubygems, string-matching

I have an array of strings

```
["2 192.168.1.101 10000",56 192.168.1.101 10001","3 192.168.1.101 10002","1 192.168.1.101 10003"]
```

I would like to get parts or each string item and create separate arrays
something like:

```
["2","56","3","1"] , ["192.168.1.101","192.168.1.101","192.168.1.101","192.168.1.101"] and
["10000","10001","10002","10003"]
```

My question is how to get those characters?

For the first Array, would it be something like from first to " " empty space get <
And for the second Array, would it be something like from " " to " "  get <
And for third something like from " " to last get <

I hope my question is well understood and I get some replies
thank u in advance!

Answer (score 5):

A little bit shorter than Jef's answer:

```
data = ["2 192.168.1.101 10000","56 192.168.1.101 10001","3 192.168.1.101 10002","1 192.168.1.101 10003"]
data.map(&:split).transpose
```

`String#split` splits on whitespace by default, and when you just need to call a method for each array entry, instead of `map { |x| x.do_something }` you can use the shorter `map(&:do_something)`.

Comment: I igored `String#split` uses whitespace as the separator. Good one ! A version shorter than yours will be quite a challenge...

Answer (score 3):

```
data = ["2 192.168.1.101 10000","56 192.168.1.101 10001","3 192.168.1.101 10002","1 192.168.1.101 10003"]
data.collect {|value| value.split(" ")}.transpose
```

Comment: Good answer, but maybe you could first assign the array to a variable so your answer appears without scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Fast and verbose version:

```
data = ["2 192.168.1.101 10000","56 192.168.1.101 10001","3 192.168.1.101 10002","1 192.168.1.101 10003"]
result = [[],[],[]]
data.each do |element|
  parts = element.split
  result[0] << parts[0]
  result[1] << parts[1]
  result[2] << parts[2]
end

puts result.inspect
```